# Como pasar un ArrayList de una clase a un metodo dentro de otra Clase?

Tags: c#, arraylist

Necesito usar un objeto `ArrayList` de objetos que tengo en una clase, dentro de un método que tengo en otra. Los archivos dentro del proyecto están separados y tengo dentro de uno, una función que trabaja sobre los atributos de los objetos dentro de la `ArrayList` y necesito pasarselos al método.

Esto lo tengo en un archivo dentro de un proyecto llamado `Alta de Producto`:

```
public class AltaDeProducto
{
    public static void alta()
    {
        ArrayList AProducto = new ArrayList();
        string respuesta = "si";
        ... 
    }
}
```

En el archivo llamado `Promociones`, donde tengo la función, no sé cómo pasarle el `ArrayList`:

```
public class Promociones
{   
    public static void descuento( ACA NO SE COMO PASARLE EL ARRAY)
    {
        foreach(Productos item in desc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tipo: " + item.tipo);
            Console.WriteLine("Marca: " + item.marca);
            Console.WriteLine("Talle: " + item.talle);
            Console.WriteLine("Precio: " + item.precio);
            // Esto es para imprimir lo que el objeto tiene.

        }
    }
```

Desde este archivo llamo a la funcion `Promociones`:

```
public static void mascara()
{
    int opcion = 1;

    while(opcion!=5)
    {       
        Console.Write("Opcion: ");
        opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Clear();
                AltaDeProducto.alta();
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Crear();
                Promociones.descuento();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Falta un poco de información. Desde donde llamas a `descuento`? Desde `AltaDeProducto`?

Comment: No, tengo otro archivo con otra clase que tiene un menu con un switch y llama a la funcion.

Comment: En ese caso, pulsa en [edit] y añádelo en tu pregunta,ya que es bastante relevante. Debes tener en cuenta que tu arraylist debe estar disponible tambien en esa nueva clase.

Comment: Listo, añadi la otra parte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver tu problema debes modificar tu método `alta` para que devuelva el `ArrayList` al método principal. Algo asi:

```
public static ArrayList alta()
{
    ArrayList AProducto = new ArrayList();
    string respuesta = "si";
    ... 

    return Aproducto;
}
```

De esa manera, en tu método principal, lo recibes en otra variable, pudiendo así usarlo para llamar a tu segundo método. Algo así:

```
public static void mascara()
{
    int opcion = 1;

    ArrayList arrAlta;

    while(opcion!=5)
    {       

    Console.Write("Opcion: ");
    opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    switch(opcion)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.Clear();
            arrAlta = AltaDeProducto.alta();
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.Crear();
            if (arrAlta !=null)
            {
                Promociones.descuento(arrAlta);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Por último, debes añadir el parámetro a tu método `Descuento`:

```
public static void descuento(ArrayList arr)
{
     ....
}
```

Un par de consideraciones extra. `ArrayList` es una clase obsoleta. Debe usarse su sustituto genérico `List<T>`. Por otro lado, ésto funciona ya que usas una clase propia del lenguaje. Si usases una clase propia, ésta debería ser pública estar disponible en todas las clases mediante `using`.

Comment: Ah! y a método Promociones.descuento(); puedo pasarle el arraylist como parámetro? Para poder usarlo dentro de la clase Promociones?

Comment: @Mariano Si,se me olvido ponerlo. Llamas asi: `Promociones.descuento(arrAlta);`. Ya edité la respuesta

Comment: Si ya toma el arraylist por parametro como me dijiste! Muchas gracias!